# Can't move mouse short distances using touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I recently got a new Lenovo Y50, and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. On my previous Dell XPS 17, the touchpad had excellent response even when moving my finger slightly -- by moving my finger a very short distance, I was able to move the mouse a pixel at a time, which was very helpful for, e.g., grabbing narrow window borders. On this new machine however, the mouse does not respond until I've moved my finger about a half-centimeter, at which point the mouse will jump a dozen pixels or so. Once the mouse is moving in this manner, I *am* able to move it arbitrarily precise distances by moving my finger more slowly. I would like to have this tight precision even if I'm not already moving the mouse. (Note: this problem does *not* occur when using a USB mouse.)

I thought disabling `noise cancellation` in `xinput` may help, so I set noise cancellation values to zero, but this didn't help. Palm detection is also set to zero. Does anyone know how to achieve mouse precision for small touchpad movements?

Thank you!

For reference, `xinput` properties:

```
$ xinput list-props 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (155):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (278): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (279):   1.750000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (280):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (281):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (282):  127, 3061, 112, 1973
    Synaptics Finger (283): 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (284):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (285):   10
    Synaptics Tap Durations (286):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (287):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (288):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (289):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (290):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (291): 45, 45
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (292): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (293):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (294): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.052507, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (295):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (296):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (297):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (298): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (299):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (300): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (301):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (302): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (303):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (304): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (305):    1000, 1000
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (306): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (307):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (308): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (309):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (310):  1
    Synaptics Gestures (311):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (312):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (313): 32, 32
    Synaptics Area (314):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (315):  1594, 0, 1709, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (316): 0, 0
    Device Product ID (271):    2, 14
    Device Node (272):  "/dev/input/event5"
```

For reference, `synclient` parameters:

```
$ synclient
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 127
    RightEdge               = 3061
    TopEdge                 = 112
    BottomEdge              = 1973
    FingerLow               = 1
    FingerHigh              = 1
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 100
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 45
    HorizScrollDelta        = 45
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0525072
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 1000
    PalmMinZ                = 1000
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 0
    VertHysteresis          = 0
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1594
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 1709
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: I have the same symptom on a Lenovo T540P trackpad, Ubuntu 14.04 (using [1.8 Synaptics driver](https://launchpad.net/~rsrchboy/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-synaptics) as has been recommended for this touchpad model).

Comment: Another [interesting factoid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man4/synaptics.4.html) for the readers:

"**Noise cancellation** *The synaptics has a built-in noise cancellation  based  on  hysteresis. This means that incoming coordinates actually shift a box of predefined dimensions such that it covers the incoming coordinate,  and  only  the boxes  own  center is used as input.*"  -- unsure if that has an effect, or, how to disable that if it's baked into the firmware...

Comment: More background: [X PointerAcceleration settings](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/) looks interesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My Lenovo t540p exhibited the same symptoms with the default acceleration profile = 1 (device dependent).

This appears to be related to XOrg's pointer acceleration and related ["acceleration profile"](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/).  If you set the device acceleration profile to -1 (none), the dead spot symptom seems to disappear though the mouse cursor moves very small distances on the display, making it very precise but fairly useless.

I switched to a **linear device acceleration profile** (`AccelerationProfile 6`) and saw immediate improvement.  The initial movement hesitation is still there but the cursor doesn't jump as it did previously.

Further research into the cause of the 'dead spot' is warranted, but it may be due to firmware behavior.  The [synaptics man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man4/synaptics.4.html) mentions firmware noise cancellation that may be difficult or impossible to control at present:

> #### Noise cancellation
>
> The synaptics has a built-in noise cancellation based on hysteresis. This means that incoming coordinates actually shift a box of predefined dimensions such that it covers the incoming coordinate, and only the boxes own center is used as input. Obviously, the smaller the box the better, but the likelyhood of noise motion coming through also increases.

#### Tweaking the acceleration profile and related config

Here's a script I use to tweak settings on my system:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEVICE="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
xinput --set-prop "$DEVICE" "Device Accel Profile" 6
xinput --set-prop "$DEVICE" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 12
xinput --set-prop "$DEVICE" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 20
```

Once you find settings you like, you may choose to add them to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf` file (copied from `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`) or create a new, separate .conf file there with a name like `99-your-config-file-name.conf`.

```
Option "AccelerationProfile" "6"
# May want to set "ConstantDeceleration" and "VelocityScale" or other 
# values here as well
```

Comment: Can't believe this has no upvotes. I have a Lenovo P50 with 16.04.1 Xubuntu and the trackpad was quite disappointing. The question describes the problem perfectly. The suggested script makes the trackpad much better. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped, @TimRichardson - Please share any findings/improvements you come up with.

Answer (score 3):

I could solve the problem for me (ThinkPad T460s) by executing:

```
$ synclient HorizHysteresis=0
$ synclient VertHysteresis=0
```

Using the synaptics configuration software `synclient`.

These parameters were already set to `0` in the original question by @MichaelTingley, but in my case they were set to 28. Setting them to zero removed the need to move the finger a little before the mouse actually moves.

These settings can be set permanently by adding this to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "HorizHysteresis" "0"
    Option "VertHysteresis" "0"
EndSection
```

And thanks to the thorough answer of @Inactivist which pointed me in the right direction.