# How to improve trackpad precision on Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, synaptics, libinput

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel is `5.4.0-99-lowlatency`, but issue is the same on the generic kernel) on a Thinkpad X260. The trackpad device is "Synaptics TM3075-002".

Basically, for small, precise movements the trackpad is jittery and sometimes doesn't register a movement.

I've tried both `libinput 1.19.901` and the latest `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package.

Cursor movement while slowing moving my finger across the trackpad w/ `libinput`:
[image: Trackpad with libinput]

Cursor movement while slowing moving my finger across the trackpad w/ `synaptics`:
[image: Trackpad with synaptics]

It's better with `synaptics` but still jumpy.

These are the properties with `libinput`:

```
Device 'Synaptics TM3075-002':
        Device Enabled (168):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (170): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Tapping Enabled (304): 1
        libinput Tapping Enabled Default (305): 0
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (306):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (307):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (308):       0
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (309):       0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (310):  1, 0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (311):  1, 0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (312):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (313):       0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (314):    0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (315):    1
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (316):        1, 1, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (317):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (318):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Click Methods Available (319): 1, 1
        libinput Click Method Enabled (320):    0, 1
        libinput Click Method Enabled Default (321):    1, 0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (322):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (323):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (324):     0.500000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (325):     0.000000
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (326):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (327):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (289):     1, 1
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (290):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (291):        0, 0
        Device Node (292):      "/dev/input/event15"
        Device Product ID (293):        1739, 0
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (328):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (329):       1
```

and with `synaptics`:

```
Device 'Synaptics TM3075-002':
        Device Enabled (168):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (170): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (301):     1
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (302):       2.500000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (303):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (304):    12.500000
        Synaptics Edges (305):  67, 1613, 54, 948
        Synaptics Finger (306): 25, 30, 0
        Synaptics Tap Time (307):       180
        Synaptics Tap Move (308):       86
        Synaptics Tap Durations (309):  180, 180, 100
        Synaptics ClickPad (310):       1
        Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (311):  0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (312):    282
        Synaptics Two-Finger Width (313):       7
        Synaptics Scrolling Distance (314):     39, 39
        Synaptics Edge Scrolling (315): 1, 0, 0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (316):   1, 0
        Synaptics Move Speed (317):     1.000000, 1.750000, 0.102249, 0.000000
        Synaptics Off (318):    0
        Synaptics Locked Drags (319):   0
        Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (320):   5000
        Synaptics Tap Action (321):     2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Click Action (322):   1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling (323):     0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (324):    0.100000
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (325):     0
        Synaptics Circular Pad (326):   0
        Synaptics Palm Detection (327): 0
        Synaptics Palm Dimensions (328):        10, 200
        Synaptics Coasting Speed (329): 20.000000, 50.000000
        Synaptics Pressure Motion (330):        30, 160
        Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (331): 1.000000, 1.000000
        Synaptics Resolution Detect (332):      1
        Synaptics Grab Event Device (333):      0
        Synaptics Gestures (334):       1
        Synaptics Capabilities (335):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
        Synaptics Pad Resolution (336): 20, 20
        Synaptics Area (337):   0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Soft Button Areas (338):      840, 0, 821, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Noise Cancellation (339):     0, 0
        Device Product ID (293):        1739, 0
        Device Node (292):      "/dev/input/event15"
```

I'm not sure what else I can do. The other properties don't seem to affect this (I disabled noise cancellation for `synaptics` but not sure how much that helped). Is there another driver I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying things I ended up finding a decent solution at [this answer to a previous question](https://askubuntu.com/a/599540/941448).

Basically I ended up changing the following properties:

```
DEVICE=11
xinput --set-prop "$DEVICE" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 0 0
xinput --set-prop "$DEVICE" "Device Accel Profile" 6
xinput --set-prop "$DEVICE" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 50
xinput --set-prop "$DEVICE" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 12
```

The key is changing the `Device Accel Profile` to `6`, which according to the linked answer is the linear acceleration profile. It takes some getting used to, but small movements are much less jumpy now:

[image: Smoother trackpad movements]

`libinput` also has [a "flat" acceleration profile](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/pointer-acceleration.html) which might be equivalent to `synaptics` linear profile, but I haven't yet had the chance to try it.